# What's the proper way to create this html chunk

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, frontend

I'm curious as to what the best way to go about creating a component of my site properly, I'm talking strictly HTML and CSS. I'm using Bootstrap 3 with jquery 3.1.1.

I'm attempting to create a sort of 3x3 pattern that will be able to demonstrate my projects properly. So I'm trying to create a single component that will I can just copy paste 8 more times.

So far I've got this for HTML

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-work-workplate">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 ignore">
                            <h2 class="portfolio-work-workplate-header">Booming Title</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph">Lorem ipsum, ecks dee gaga enjoy memeius!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And here is the SCSS

```
    .portfolio-work-workplate{
  text-align: center;
  height: 15vw;
  background:green;
}

.portfolio-work-workplate-header{
  // display:flex;
  // align-items: flex-start;
  // background:blue;
  // justify-content: center;

}

.portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph{
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0,150%);
// display: flex;
//   align-items: center;
//   text-align: center;
}
```

I left my failure comments in because I was attempting to use flexbox but kept running into a weird issue where it would basically just have the H2 and the P literally neck and neck, and anything I did to them was pointless because they weren't moving.

The goal of this is to create a hunk of code that looks like  [ Top:Title, Bottom:Some words or a date ] and I'm trying to include []'s because I want to keep some sort of aesthetic.

I was thinking of creating it in 4 different sections in a giant container. Two on the sides with []'s on them and two inners that the top is a title and the bottom is some text or a date. But I've failed several times over the last few hours here.

Edit: For clarification, I can create a basic layout for it, but I'm wanting something that's more along the lines of high level. I'm sorry for any confusion. Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqexL.png) for the end game of the single component.

Comment: Why don't you use tables

Comment: *I'm talking strictly HTML and CSS. I'm using Bootstrap 3 with jquery 3.1.1.* ...

Comment: @Bálint Do you see tabular data?

Comment: *sort of 3x3 pattern* Here this sounds quite tabular to me

Comment: What does the 3x3 *layout* say about the data? Tabular data consists of columns of type-identical data. Columns are not even mentioned by OP.

Comment: connexo is right. Tabular data talks about the *content* not about the *presentation*. Tabular data is the kind of stuff you'd use in an Excel worksheet.

Comment: For any sort of clearing up, I'm wanting to create something similar to this. https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/3-col-portfolio/

However I'm trying to make it go full screen, and when my media queries hit I'm going to make it a 1x9 grid. Unfortunately I may have not conveyed that properly. I'm sorry for any confusion! I've honestly never used tables, and I'm not sure how they would really come into this. Are they able to be split apart with media queries if so, I'm very unaware of it.

Comment: My answer achieves just that.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is a [*grid*](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#grid-options). Display the snippet as full screen to see the grid. If you want a grid that never goes to a single column on smaller resolutions, you should change the `col-sm-4` class to `col-xs-4`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-work-workplate">
      <h2 class="portfolio-work-workplate-header">Booming Title</h2>
      <p class="portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph">Lorem ipsum, ecks dee gaga enjoy memeius!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-work-workplate">
      <h2 class="portfolio-work-workplate-header">Booming Title</h2>
      <p class="portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph">Lorem ipsum, ecks dee gaga enjoy memeius!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-work-workplate">
      <h2 class="portfolio-work-workplate-header">Booming Title</h2>
      <p class="portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph">Lorem ipsum, ecks dee gaga enjoy memeius!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-work-workplate">
      <h2 class="portfolio-work-workplate-header">Booming Title</h2>
      <p class="portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph">Lorem ipsum, ecks dee gaga enjoy memeius!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-work-workplate">
      <h2 class="portfolio-work-workplate-header">Booming Title</h2>
      <p class="portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph">Lorem ipsum, ecks dee gaga enjoy memeius!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-work-workplate">
      <h2 class="portfolio-work-workplate-header">Booming Title</h2>
      <p class="portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph">Lorem ipsum, ecks dee gaga enjoy memeius!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-work-workplate">
      <h2 class="portfolio-work-workplate-header">Booming Title</h2>
      <p class="portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph">Lorem ipsum, ecks dee gaga enjoy memeius!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-work-workplate">
      <h2 class="portfolio-work-workplate-header">Booming Title</h2>
      <p class="portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph">Lorem ipsum, ecks dee gaga enjoy memeius!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 portfolio-work-workplate">
      <h2 class="portfolio-work-workplate-header">Booming Title</h2>
      <p class="portfolio-work-workplate-paragraph">Lorem ipsum, ecks dee gaga enjoy memeius!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```